# Switching Images By XML in Android

Tags: android, image, switch-statement, togglebutton

Hey guys.I'm new to android and with the help of stackoverflow I somehow managed to switch between images by checking for state using an xml and changing the image. Now I have another togglebutton in the same activity,so is there any way to use the same xml to do the switching or do I have to create a new one ? Because the images are different.

This is the xml code I used from this site .

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" 
         android:drawable="@drawable/pause" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/play" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
  </selector>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create another selector with the drawables for the second togglebutton, since here's no info except drawable per state, so you have nothing common in 2 togglebuttons' selectors.

Answer (score 2):

For each image that you want an "On / Off" behavior or switchable using android:state you will have to have another code block for each toggleButton